# Jquery does not detect changes in checkbox after load()

Tags: jquery, django

This code detects the change checkbox only once. After I use the load () function is not detected another change in the checkbox.

Which solution to this problem?

Thanks,

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkTask").on("change", changed);
});


function changed() {
    var id = $(this).attr("idTask");
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    // Checked
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $.post("/link/", {id: id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken}, function (data) {
            $("#tableTask").load(location.href + " #tableTask>*");
        });
    }
    // Unchecked
    else {
        $.post("/link/", {
            id: id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
        }, function (data) {
            $("#tableTask").load(location.href + " #tableTask>*");
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody id="tableTask">
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <input class="checkTask" type="checkbox" idTask="{{ task.id }}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the `$("#tableTask")` container for this checkbox ?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov yes!

Comment: Well actually the html you added to your question says the opposite.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov sorry, I edited now! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload contents for `$("#tableTask")` in the ajax callback you wipe out the checkbox event handler you had there before.

Rewrite `$(".checkTask").on("change", changed);` to:

```
$(document).on("change", ".checkTask", changed);
```

or

```
$("#tableTask").on("change", ".checkTask", changed);
```

so you will keep adding this event handler to newly created checkboxes.

Comment: @GuileGarcia note this is called `event delegation` and you will use it often  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/